# What web browser engine, version, and capabilities are used to display web pages inside Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2010

My company is developing a plugin/add-on for Visual Studio 2010. When the user asks to display the help for our product, we plan on opening an HTML page (or suite of pages) within Visual Studio. I'm helping to design and implement the help system.

1. What web engine/version is used within Visual Studio 2010? [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) it is *not* Trident(!).

   - <sub>`navigator.userAgent` reports: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)`</sub>
2. Am I allowed to load remote JavaScript content (via a `<script>` element)?
3. Am I allowed to use [XHR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28VS.85%29.aspx) to load remote content?
4. Will my page be trusted and have access to the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

I would appreciate any resources you can give me on programming specifically to the 'web' capabilities of VisualStudio2010-as-a-browser.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what happens if you create this help and have it echo `user-agent`? I'm finding it *very* hard to believe that VS.Net 2010's renderer isn't Trident, Wikipedia or no (esp. as that comment is not cited).

Comment: @TJCrowder Good question! I bothered one of the engineers and got them to alert the user agent; I've updated the question with the details.

Comment: So, it's Trident. The Wikipedia article is wrong. Not particularly surprising.

Comment: @TJCrowder Can you be sure of that? If it's another custom engine developed by MS, they likely would have included "Trident" for compatibility with UA-sniffing scripts. My copy of IE8, for example, still reports "MSIE 7.0" despite what [Microsoft claims it should report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[From a 2007 blog by Microsoft's Rob Mauceri](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/11/office-live-and-sharepoint.aspx#2159217), it seems that Microsoft has developed a new layout engine for development purposes:

> SharePoint Designer, Expression Web, and the next version of Visual Studio's Visual Web Designer (code name Orcas) all use the same stanards-based web design component. This component was developed jointly by the three product teams for high fidelity rendering of web standards like CSS, XHTML, as well as ASP.net.

This was about Visual Studio 2008, but my guess is that it will be the same for 2010.